# Remove part of string KDB

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a table named "t", with column, "x". It looks as follows:

```
x
------
1.Fred
2.Joe
3.Hank
.
.
.
500.Mary
```

I need to take the column and remove everything before the name, for example the "1." before Fred.

I have tried 
    update `$2_'string x from t` but that only works for numbers 1-9 not once I get to the larger numbers. Is there a way to remove the "." and everything before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more approach, which helps to cover case when name has '.':

```
update x:`${(1+x ?\:".")_'x} string x from  t
```

The logic is

1. Convert symbol column `x` to string
2. Get index of first dot in every element of list of strings `1+x ?\:"."`
3. Cut characters before the first dot `(1+x ?\:".")_'x`

Next model can be used for testing:

```
//Create table with 100 random names
t: ([] ID: til 100; x: `$(string 1+til 100),'".",'(?[;"abc"] each 1+100?9),'" ",'(?[;"def"] each 1+100?9));
//Replace space with dot for the last 10 names
t: update x: `$ssr[;" ";"."]'[string x] from t where ID>90;
update x:`${(1+x ?\:".")_'x} string x from  t
```

Though using `0:` proposed by @Ryan McCarron is obviously faster. If you sure there are no additional dots, that approach is preferable.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `0:` for this - it's often the best approach for lists of strings, and works particularly well for longer lists compared to using find and drop, or `vs`:

```
q)update raze(" *";".")0:string c from t
x
----
Fred
Joe
Hank
Mary
```

This is efficiently splitting the string on the `"."`, throwing away the first column of the return (by not specifying it in `" *"`, the first element of the left arg to `0:`), and then giving an enlisted return, which needs to be razed to return it to a list of strings which will fit back in the column.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming x is a column of symbol type:

```
q)update `$last each "."vs'string x from t
x
----
Fred
Joe
Hank
Mary
```

This utilizes a combination of the function vs with the adverb each-both:
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#vs
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both

Comment: You don't need to string and cast... last each` vs'x would work

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting it done is:

```
q)select (` vs/:x)[;1] from t
x
----
Fred
Joe
Hank
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way to get this result by using inter and .Q namespace

```
 t:update {`$x inter .Q.a,.Q.A} each string x from t
    
    x
    ----
    Fred
    Joe
    Hang
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qa-upper-case-alphabet 
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/inter/